# How does foistware bundle work?

Tags: ads

It seems like foistware uses similar mechanism to ads.  As I understand website ads work by having a placeholder linked to `ads.com/intrusive/...?from-my-site,...` When visitor goes to the site this placeholder brings him to ads.com. Now ads.com check visitor's `id cookie` (and drops a new one if isn't there). Finally is shows some ads.

Is my understanding of ads mechanics correct?

Is foistware mechanics similar to ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to ask Unckecky developers. It seems like most of bundles download adware payload once you start installing the app. Installing bundled software while online often prevents adware from installing.